# Add a service with space in path and arguments

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I am trying to create a service for vc x server but the command times out via service but I can run it directly from command line

```
C:\Users\Vishwa Pravin>sc.exe create vcxsrv binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe\" :2 -ac -terminate  -lesspointer -multiwindow -clipboard -wgl -dpi auto" displayname= "VC X Server"
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

C:\Users\Vishwa Pravin>sc.exe start vcxsrv
[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.


C:\Users\Vishwa Pravin> "C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe" :2 -ac -terminate  -lesspointer -multiwindow -clipboard -wgl -dpi auto

C:\Users\Vishwa Pravin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services on Windows need to do a bit more than ordinary programs – they need to answer to the "service control" messages sent by Service Manager, e.g. indicating that they're ready (fully started). VcxSrv doesn't do that (thus the "did not respond" error message), so you would need to run it through something like `srvany` or [`srvany-ng`](https://github.com/birkett/srvany-ng) instead of directly.

(Also, services on Windows do not have access to your GUI environment – they're *services,* by definition they aren't GUI apps. It's possible to mark them as "interactive" services so that they'd get access to the console display, but it won't work all that well with multi-user systems or RDP connections, and it's a bit dangerous considering that currently you're trying to run the service with "SYSTEM" privileges – higher than even an administrator, and something an X11 server definitely doesn't need.)